# Show content of online server file on android app

Tags: java, android, json, listview, fileserver

I am currently making an app where the user can access study material from a list view of different subjects.

In my database table where the subject names are fetched from also has a column which has a file path to a folder on my online server. Each subject has an individual folder on the server.

How would I go about adding to my code so that when a user clicks on a subject on the list, the content of their specific folder displays on a new activity?

here is my code at the moment of a simple list view:

```
 public class FindMaterialActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list;
private ArrayList<String> subjects;
private JSONArray result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_material2);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

    getData();

}

private void getData() {
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(SubConfig.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(SubConfig.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getSubjects(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getSubjects(JSONArray j) {
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            subjects.add(json.getString(SubConfig.TAG_SUBJECTS));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindMaterialActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subjects));
}
}
```

and subject config.java

```
  public class SubConfig {

    //JSON URL
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://opuna.co.uk/subject_api/FetchSub.php";

    //Tags used in the JSON String
    public static final String TAG_SUBJECTS = "Subject_Name";
    public static final String TAG_SUB_ID = "Sub_id";


    //JSON array name
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the meta about the sub folders in your database as you did for subjects and get the meta using JSON in your app as you got for subjects and show them in a custom layout made of your own.